# LOOP itab vs VALUE FOR filtering, which is more efficient?

Tags: loops, abap, internal-tables

I am trying to write a for-loop statement for the following scenario:

I have used a select to get multiple `tvarvc` entries data into `T_TVARVC`.

```
LOOP AT t_tvarvc INTO DATA(s_tvarvc).
    CASE s_tvarvc-name.
      WHEN c_augru.
        s_tvarvc_range = CORRESPONDING #( s_tvarvc ).
        APPEND s_tvarvc_range TO t_augru.

      WHEN c_vkorg.
        s_tvarvc_range = CORRESPONDING #( s_tvarvc ).
        APPEND s_tvarvc_range TO t_vkorg.
    ENDCASE.
ENDLOOP.
```

This is what I have come up with:

```
DATA(t_augru) = VALUE tt_tvarvc( FOR s_tvarvc IN t_tvarvc
                                  WHERE ( name = c_augru )
                                  ( CORRESPONDING #( s_tvarvc ) ) ).

DATA(t_vkorg) = VALUE tt_tvarvc( FOR s_tvarvc IN t_tvarvc
                                  WHERE ( name = c_vkorg )
                                  ( CORRESPONDING #( s_tvarvc ) ) ).
```

My observation is that, by using `LOOP AT` and `CASE` statement combo, the number of iterations will be same as the number of entries in `T_TVARVC`. 
But when using a `FOR` loop for each range table, `T_TVARVC` has to be traversed more times to reach the desired entry thus causing multiple iterations more than the first scenario.

Can this be written in a more efficient way?

Comment: Traversing the table multiple times is not necessarily slower, especially if the WHERE condition is backed by an index. Have you checked the actual performance (with e.g. transaction SAT and some sample data representing a real world usecase)?

Comment: @Jonas yeah I checked the performance with data and `LOOP AT` came on top. In my case, there is not much data so there is no issue of the program getting slower.

Comment: @RaviRishie But you've no sorted (secondary) key on `name`, right? As Jonas mentioned, having such a key might perform much faster. But code snipped and data size + write frequency would need to be judged.

Comment: @peterulb I dont have any specifically mentioned but have added an explicit sort on `name` and `low`.

Comment: If there is "not much data", I'd go with the `FOR` as it is more readable IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your observation about doubling the iterations, and to make it faster, I think the only solution is to use only one loop, considering that the internal table is not already sorted, which limits the possible solutions a lot, and I come to this solution:

```
TYPES: tt_tvarvc TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tvarvc WITH EMPTY KEY,
       BEGIN OF ty_ranges,
         t_augru TYPE tt_tvarvc,
         t_vkorg TYPE tt_tvarvc,
       END OF ty_ranges.
CONSTANTS: c_augru TYPE tvarvc-name VALUE 'AUGRU',
           c_vkorg TYPE tvarvc-name VALUE 'VKORG'.

DATA(t_tvarvc) = VALUE tt_tvarvc( for i = 1 while i <= 100 ( name = c_augru ) 
                                                           ( name = c_vkorg ) ).
DATA(ranges) = REDUCE ty_ranges(
                  INIT ranges2 = VALUE ty_ranges( )
                  FOR <tvarv> IN t_tvarvC
                  NEXT ranges2-t_augru = COND #( WHEN <tvarv>-name = c_augru
                                              THEN VALUE #( BASE ranges2-t_augru ( <tvarv> ) )
                                              ELSE ranges2-t_augru )
                       ranges2-t_vkorg = COND #( WHEN <tvarv>-name = c_vkorg
                                              THEN VALUE #( BASE ranges2-t_vkorg ( <tvarv> ) )
                                              ELSE ranges2-t_vkorg ) ).
```

(you will use `ranges-t_augru` and `ranges-t_vkorg` instead of `t_augru` and `t_vkorg` in your code)

You can immediately see that the code is much less legible than any of your two snippets.

Moreover, there is no gain in performance compared to your classic loop.

Back to your snippet with two FOR iterations, we can see that the goal is very clear compared to the classic loop (my opinion). It's of course slower, but probably you don't need to gain a few microseconds, and so I think it's the best solution (still my opinion).

Comment: This is great. Thank you for the edits and your opinion. Yes, `FOR` loop shows what I am exactly trying to achieve. I was just worried about writing lines of code with recurring statements. 
Your snippet is wonderful and I got to learn a few things from it too. I'll definitely try it out.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another answer relating to the part

```
My observation is that, by using LOOP AT and CASE statement combo, the number of iterations will be same as the number of entries in T_TVARVC.
But when using a FOR loop for each range table, T_TVARVC has to be traversed more times to reach the desired entry thus causing multiple iterations more than the first scenario.
```

This is only true when you've no sorted index for the field in question. Assume instead of `WHERE ( name = c_vkorg )` you use `USING KEY sk_name WHERE ( object = c_vkorg  )`. This will know the index where the values you are searching for are starting in log n time. It will then only process the lines matching the key, never looping over anything else.
This can potentially save a huge amount of time.

| Index | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 (sorted index) |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 9999 | AAA |  |
| 2 | B | 1213 | AAB |  |
| 3 | C | 554 | AAC |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| 500 | X | 1 | AUGUR | <-- Starting here with loop |

The downside is that a sorted secondary key will also take time to build (and some memory). This can be less of an issue if you have other code also requiring fast access.
The secondary keys are lazy, so the first time they are used is the time they'll be created.

In your scenario, you have to decide what's worth it. Are there frequent read accesses requiring the key? How many rows? Is it more expensive to build up the key access because the key isn't needed elsewhere? How often will the secondary key be invalidated, etc etc.

(Note: If you uncomment the xsdbool, you exclude the time it takes to build the secondary key from the measurement).

```
REPORT ztest.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  PERFORM standard.
  PERFORM sorted_secondary.
  PERFORM sorted_secondary_val.

FORM standard.
  DATA t_tadir TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tadir WITH EMPTY KEY.
  DATA t_clas TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tadir-obj_name WITH EMPTY KEY.
  DATA t_tran TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tadir-obj_name WITH EMPTY KEY.

  SELECT * FROM tadir UP TO 1000000 ROWS INTO TABLE @t_tadir ORDER BY PRIMARY KEY.
*  DATA(dummy) = xsdbool( line_exists( t_tadir[ key primary_key object = 'CLAS' ] ) ).

  GET RUN TIME FIELD DATA(t1).
  LOOP AT t_tadir ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<s_tadir>).
    CASE <s_tadir>-object.
      WHEN 'CLAS'.
        APPEND <s_tadir>-obj_name TO t_clas.

      WHEN 'TRAN'.
        APPEND <s_tadir>-obj_name TO t_tran.
    ENDCASE.
  ENDLOOP.
  GET RUN TIME FIELD DATA(t2).
  WRITE: |{ ( t2 - t1 ) / '1000.0' / '1000.0' }, { lines( t_tadir ) }, { lines( t_clas ) }, { lines( t_tran ) }|.
  NEW-LINE.
ENDFORM.

FORM sorted_secondary.
  DATA t_tadir TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tadir WITH NON-UNIQUE SORTED KEY sk_object COMPONENTS object.
  DATA t_clas TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tadir-obj_name WITH EMPTY KEY.
  DATA t_tran TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tadir-obj_name WITH EMPTY KEY.

  SELECT * FROM tadir UP TO 1000000 ROWS INTO TABLE @t_tadir ORDER BY PRIMARY KEY.
*  DATA(dummy) = xsdbool( line_exists( t_tadir[ key sk_object object = 'CLAS' ] ) ).

  GET RUN TIME FIELD DATA(t1).
  LOOP AT t_tadir ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<s_tadir>) USING KEY sk_object WHERE object = 'CLAS'.
    APPEND <s_tadir>-obj_name TO t_clas.
  ENDLOOP.
  LOOP AT t_tadir ASSIGNING <s_tadir> USING KEY sk_object WHERE object = 'TRAN'.
    APPEND <s_tadir>-obj_name TO t_tran.
  ENDLOOP.
  GET RUN TIME FIELD DATA(t2).
  WRITE: |{ ( t2 - t1 ) / '1000.0' / '1000.0' }, { lines( t_tadir ) }, { lines( t_clas ) }, { lines( t_tran ) }|.
  NEW-LINE.
ENDFORM.

FORM sorted_secondary_val.
  DATA t_tadir TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tadir WITH NON-UNIQUE SORTED KEY sk_object COMPONENTS object.
  DATA t_clas TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tadir-obj_name WITH EMPTY KEY.
  DATA t_tran TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF tadir-obj_name WITH EMPTY KEY.

  SELECT * FROM tadir UP TO 1000000 ROWS INTO TABLE @t_tadir ORDER BY PRIMARY KEY.
*  DATA(dummy) = xsdbool( line_exists( t_tadir[ key sk_object object = 'CLAS' ] ) ).

  GET RUN TIME FIELD DATA(t1).
  t_clas = VALUE #( for <fs> in t_tadir USING KEY sk_object WHERE ( object = 'CLAS' ) ( <fs>-obj_name ) ).
  t_tran = VALUE #( for <fs> in t_tadir USING KEY sk_object WHERE ( object = 'TRAN' ) ( <fs>-obj_name ) ).
  GET RUN TIME FIELD DATA(t2).
  WRITE: |{ ( t2 - t1 ) / '1000.0' / '1000.0' }, { lines( t_tadir ) }, { lines( t_clas ) }, { lines( t_tran ) }|.
  NEW-LINE.
ENDFORM.
```

Also: `LOOP AT ... ASSIGNING/REFERENCE INTO` is likely to be faster than `LOOP AT ... INTO`. Since you make no write access that shouldn't be reflected in the original data source, there's no reason to copy every line in every loop step.

Comment: I pasted your code and several runs weirdly confirmed the same result which contradicts your statements: the first `standard` variant with `case` without any keys was always double-faster then the second twos.  This reveals the simple truth: one loop is always better than two

Comment: @Suncatcher Did you include the secondary key creation in your measurement? In many real world cases, the secondary key would be created earlier and read at multiple locations (uncomment the dummy line). If you create the secondary key for this read access only, it's likely it will be slower (as sorting is at least n log n).

Comment: well, yes, with dummy lines the results are turned upside down. However I think methodologically it is correct to measure runtime with sec key generation. Simple loop doesn't use secondary key and calculated as is, and for 2nd/3rd variants sec key is an integral part of design, so it should be included

Comment: @Suncatcher As mentioned in the answer, it depends. If you create the secondary key only for this loop, it's a bad idea. Then of course having one loop over all entries is faster. But if you know you'll need this index access more often, then secondary key is a great fit. Like imagine the method in question being called 1 Million times. Then the sorting cost will occur once. But the reading improvement will be in 1 million calls. For 1 call it's indeed pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try specialized [FILTER](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenconstructor_expr_filter_basic.htm) statement to achieve the same:

```
DATA lt_tadir TYPE SORTED TABLE OF tadir WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY object. 

SELECT * FROM tadir UP TO 1000000 ROWS INTO TABLE lt_tadir ORDER BY PRIMARY KEY. 

DATA(clas) = FILTER #( lt_tadir USING KEY primary_key WHERE object = 'CLAS' ). 
DATA(trans) = FILTER #( lt_tadir USING KEY primary_key WHERE object = 'TRAN' ).
```

I took the snippet prepared by @peterulb for 1M table and here are my measurements:

> **0.032947**, 1000000, 128776, 0 <- **FILTER** 
> **0.139579**, 1000000, 128776, 0 <- **standard** 
> **0.239092**, 1000000, 128776, 0 <- **sorted_secondary** 
> **0.242161**, 1000000, 128776, 0 <- **sorted_secondary_val**

Despite `FILTER` uses inline declarations and transfers **all** source fields into the result table (it is by design), it is executed magnitude faster than the other variants.

I do not insist it will be the rule of thumb on all databases, but at least ABAP 7.54 on HANADB utilizes some built-in optimizations for FILTER statement.